# "This shouldn't take long" showing long time while try to upload document to the document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2016, sharepoint-standard

*SharePoint 2016 Standard Edition*

When I try to upload an document to the document library, it shows "This shouldn't take long" for longtime. Approximately it takes 5 mins to show metadata forms.

Check-in also issue, it shows the following error message after loading longtime, "The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again."

**Note:** Server CPU Utilization and Memory looks fine. **I checked in Chrome and IE.** All libraries working fine in the same Site Collection other than this. The difference between this library(errored) and other library is, I created overlay in the calendar for this library.

Comment: Do you have a unique permission in this library?

Comment: Yes. All the libraries in the site having unique permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur If the library has **unique** permissions and a user/group has permissions **only** on that library and has limited or no access at the site level.

So try to grant this user/group at least **read** access to the site level to avoid this issue!

For more details check [The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/02/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: No luck. I am the Site collection admin and having Full control permission over the site and libraries. This issue only for two libraries which i created calendar overlay in the Site calendar. And i also checked by removing those overlays still same issue.

Comment: More Info: The library which created using that template also same issue.